# Big-O & Exact Runtime

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am learning about Big-O and although I started to understand things, I still am not able to correctly measure the Big-O of an algorithm.
I've got a code:

```c
int n = 10;
int count = 0;
int k = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
  for (int p = 200; p > 2*i; p--)
  {
    int j = i;
    while (j < n)
     {
      do
        {
         count++;
         k = count * j;
        } while (k > j);
        j++;
     }
  }
}
```

which I have to measure the Big-O and Exact Runtime.

Let me start, the first `for` loop is `O(n)` because it depends on `n` variable. 
The second `for` loop is nested, therefore makes the big-O till now an `O(n^2)`.

So how we gonna calculate the `while (j < n)` (so only three loops till now) and how we gonna calculate the `do while(k > j)` if it appears, makes 4 loops, such as in this case? 
A comprehend explanation would be really helpful. 
Thank you.

Comment: not enough familiar with big-o notation, but not sure if the two nested for are really n^2, as if n>100, when i>100 the second loop won't do anything

Comment: Well, typically (but not always) the two `for` nested loops will produce an `O(n^2)`. 
In this case, I think it does.

Comment: it's O(n^2) in the [0-100] range, but big-o is calculated with infinite n...

Comment: But if it's >100 then it wouldn't enter the second loop, and the program would not be executed?!

Comment: it would be, but only for the first 100 i

Comment: I think you are confusing Big-O with Big-Omega here. Especially since you ask about *exact runtime*. Sounds like you are interested in the lower bound (Big-Omega) instead of an upper bound (Big-O). Or even for Theta (exact bound). I mean, even a constant program is in `O(n)`, `O(n^2)`, `O(exp(n))`, ... it's just an upper bound.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for the complexity of a code that is not OK.

Comment: This was one of the programming's exam question. The question is as follows "Find the Big O-notation and Exact Runtime for the code below. Justify your answer" 
So it is asking about Big-Oh, not Omega.

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm much mistaken, this program has an infinite loop and therefore it's time complexity cannot usefully be analyzed.
In particular

```
do
    {
         count++;
         k = count * j;
    } while (k > j);
```

as soon as this loop is entered for the second time and `count = 2`, `k` will be set greater to `j`, and will remain so indefinitely (ignoring integer overflow, which will happen pretty quickly).

I understand that you're learning Big-Oh notation, but creating toy examples like this probably isn't the best way to understand Big-Oh. I would recommend reading a well-known algorithms textbook where they walk you through new algorithms, explaining and analyzing the time and space complexity as they do so.

Comment: This was one of programming exam's question, last year. "Calculate the Big-O and Exact Runtime of this code... and explain why."

Interestingly, I just debugged the code and the results at the end of calculation (took some seconds, full 100% CPU on dual-core pentium) are: 
`n = 10, count = -238600651, k = -2147405859`

I think i'll stick again to more simple questions and basic examples, before moving onto this one. It just somehow attracted my attention.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the while loop should be:

```
while (k < j)
```

Now, in this case, the first for loop would take O(n) time. The second loop would take O(p) time. 
Now, for the third loop,

```
int j = i;`
while (j < n){
...
j++;
}
```

could be rewritten as

```
for(j=i;j<n;j++)
```

meaning it shall take O(n) time.
For the last loop, the value of k increases exponentially.
Consider it to be same as

```
for(k = count*j ;k<j ;j++,count++)
```

Hence it shall take O(logn) time.

The total time complexity is O(n^2*p*logn).